# Problema con vector

Tags: android, vectores

Estoy importando algunos svg con Vector Asset Estudio, en uno de ellos me aparece este aviso.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ruta vectorial muy larga.

Mi pregunta es, ¿podría ignorarlo? ya que este vector creado se mostrará una sola vez dentro de un ImageView.

Mi vector es el siguiente :

```
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:autoMirrored="true"
    android:viewportWidth="512"
    android:viewportHeight="512">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:pathData="M413.5,1c-1.1,0.4 -5.6,1.3 -10,2 -14.9,2.2 -34.5,8.8 -50,16.8 -43.4,22.5 -76,63 -88.6,110 -5.3,19.9 -5.2,19.4 -5.8,103.2l-0.6,78.5 -3,0.3c-5,0.5 -16.7,4.3 -22.5,7.2 -18.4,9.3 -31.2,24.9 -37.6,45.6 -2.8,9.3 -2.6,30.7 0.4,39.8 5.9,17.7 15.7,30.7 30.1,40 13.7,8.7 24.9,11.8 41.9,11.5 6.1,-0.1 11.4,-0 11.6,0.2 0.3,0.3 1.2,4 2,8.4 4.8,24.7 8.6,39.4 15.3,59.5 11,33.2 31.4,63.2 59.1,87.1l4.2,3.7 -2.5,19.8c-6,47 -5.8,45.9 -10.2,55.1 -5.2,11.1 -13.9,20.2 -23.3,24.5 -9.2,4.2 -4.7,3.6 -57,7.7 -14.6,1.1 -33.2,2.5 -41.5,3.1 -8.2,0.6 -18.1,1.5 -22,2.1 -15,2.1 -29.6,4.5 -36.5,6 -2.5,0.6 -6.5,1.5 -9,2 -16.5,3.7 -31.6,9.2 -46.6,17 -39.4,20.5 -69.8,51.5 -89.9,91.8 -3.6,7.1 -6.5,13.4 -6.5,14 0,0.6 -0.4,1.9 -0.9,2.9 -3.4,6.1 -9.3,27.8 -11,40.2 -0.7,4.7 -1.6,9.9 -2.2,11.6 -0.5,1.8 -0.9,35.1 -0.9,80.2 0,84.3 -0.4,78.1 5.4,83.1 1,0.9 2.4,2.2 3.1,2.8 1.1,1 101,1.3 492.8,1.3 285.1,-0 492.6,-0.4 494.3,-0.9 1.6,-0.5 5.6,-1.5 8.9,-2.2 7.1,-1.5 17.9,-5.8 25.5,-10.1 23.1,-13 41.6,-37.6 47,-62.8 0.7,-3 1.6,-6.8 2.1,-8.4 1.3,-4.2 1.2,-299.4 -0.1,-300.9 -0.6,-0.7 -2,-2.4 -3.1,-4 -4.6,-6.1 -5.3,-6.2 -40.4,-6.2 -29.2,-0 -32.3,0.2 -35.7,1.9 -9.9,4.8 -10.5,19.2 -1.1,25.3 2.3,1.6 5.8,1.9 26.3,2.3l23.5,0.5 0.8,28.5c0.4,15.7 0.8,77.8 1,138l0.2,109.5 -2.2,7.8c-7.1,24.7 -25.3,43 -50,50l-7.8,2.2 -202,0.3c-111.1,0.2 -203.5,-0 -205.3,-0.3l-3.2,-0.6 0.2,-167.7 0.3,-167.7 101.5,-0.5c94.9,-0.5 101.8,-0.6 104.3,-2.3 5,-3.3 7.8,-10.3 6.3,-16.1 -0.8,-3.3 -5.3,-8.5 -8.5,-9.9 -1.9,-0.9 -25.1,-1.3 -83.1,-1.7l-80.5,-0.5 -0.8,-4.5c-0.4,-2.5 -2.5,-18 -4.6,-34.4l-3.8,-29.9 13.6,-13.6c24.1,-24 37.5,-42.9 46.5,-65.5 6.7,-17 14.3,-43.9 17.6,-62.1 0.7,-3.9 1.6,-8.3 2.1,-9.9 0.5,-1.6 0.9,-4 0.9,-5.2 0,-2.4 0.1,-2.4 10.5,-2.4 5.7,-0 12.8,-0.5 15.7,-1.1 27.8,-5.6 50,-26.9 56.3,-53.9 5.9,-25.3 -1,-49.9 -19.3,-68.6 -9.1,-9.3 -19.6,-15.1 -33.7,-18.9l-8,-2.2 -0.6,-79.4c-0.6,-79 -0.8,-82.6 -4.4,-97.4 -10.7,-43.8 -37.4,-81.7 -74.5,-105.8 -10.3,-6.7 -19.1,-11.2 -32.5,-16.7 -7.8,-3.3 -15.7,-5.6 -29.5,-8.7 -10.5,-2.3 -20.2,-2.6 -85.5,-2.9 -39,-0.2 -71.9,0.1 -73,0.6zM558.9,31.1c33.6,5.6 58.1,18 81.2,40.9 17.6,17.5 23.7,26.6 33.8,50.5 1.8,4.1 3.1,8.2 5,15.5 4.5,17.6 4.6,19.6 4.6,68.5l0,47 -6.9,-0.2c-21.9,-0.5 -44.6,-14.1 -58.3,-34.8 -5.5,-8.3 -8.5,-16.5 -12.8,-34.5 -4.2,-17.7 -5.6,-21.2 -9.6,-24.1 -3.7,-2.6 -12.6,-2.8 -16.3,-0.4 -4.4,2.9 -3.9,1.9 -19.8,45 -0.6,1.6 -1.5,3.4 -2,3.9 -0.4,0.6 -0.8,3.5 -0.8,6.5 0,4.2 0.5,6.1 2.5,8.7 6.4,8.4 16.5,8.3 24,-0.3l2.3,-2.7 2.7,5.4c10,19.9 27.4,36.5 49,47 11.9,5.8 22.7,8.8 35.4,10 5.1,0.5 9.8,1.3 10.3,1.8 1.6,1.6 0.3,70.9 -1.5,80.2 -1.5,7.5 -5.2,25.3 -6.7,32 -0.4,1.9 -1.3,6 -2,9 -0.7,3 -1.6,7.1 -2,9 -1.4,6.2 -7.8,37.3 -9.4,45.5 -3.5,17.8 -5.3,25.1 -9.7,40.2 -0.5,1.8 -1.3,4.8 -1.8,6.5 -7.2,25.8 -21.9,50.5 -41,69.1 -21.8,21.1 -42.8,34.1 -70.1,43.5 -20.3,6.9 -31.4,8.7 -55,8.7 -22.6,-0 -32.3,-1.4 -51.1,-7.5 -13.4,-4.4 -27.9,-11.2 -39.7,-18.7 -13.5,-8.6 -32.4,-25.6 -40.7,-36.8 -1.6,-2.2 -3.3,-4.2 -3.6,-4.5 -0.3,-0.3 -2.8,-3.9 -5.6,-8 -6.8,-10.2 -15.5,-28.3 -19.7,-41 -3.3,-10.2 -10.3,-37.6 -12.5,-49.3 -0.6,-3.1 -1.6,-8.3 -2.2,-11.5 -0.6,-3.1 -1.5,-7.5 -1.9,-9.7 -0.5,-2.2 -1.9,-8.5 -3,-14 -1.9,-9 -2.7,-12.8 -4.4,-20.5 -0.4,-1.4 -2,-8.8 -3.6,-16.5 -1.7,-7.7 -3.5,-15.8 -4,-18 -2.6,-11.4 -3.1,-21.6 -2.8,-54l0.3,-34 101.2,-0.5 101.1,-0.5 3.8,-3c2.2,-1.8 4.4,-4.8 5.3,-7.3 1.4,-3.8 1.4,-4.6 0,-8.4 -0.9,-2.5 -3.1,-5.5 -5.3,-7.3l-3.8,-3 -101.4,-0.3 -101.4,-0.2 0,-47.3c0,-52.2 0.5,-58 6.3,-75.7 7.3,-22.4 18.9,-41.3 36.2,-58.6 12.3,-12.3 23.8,-20.5 39.2,-27.9 10.2,-5 11.8,-5.6 16.8,-7.3 8.9,-2.8 14.5,-4.2 25,-6.1 7.5,-1.3 138.3,-1.3 146.4,-0zM259.4,351.2c0.9,12 2.6,22.9 6.6,40.8 3,13.5 7,32.3 7,33 0,1.3 -7.1,1.7 -13.8,0.9 -8.5,-1 -17.5,-5.6 -23.9,-12.1 -8.5,-8.8 -12.3,-17.9 -12.3,-29.7 0,-11.9 4.2,-22.1 12.6,-30.5 6,-6 15.7,-11.3 21,-11.5 2,-0.1 2.2,0.6 2.8,9.1zM721.2,344.4c11.5,5.1 19.7,13.9 23.8,25.2 1.8,5.2 2.1,7.8 1.8,16.1 -0.3,8.7 -0.7,10.6 -3.5,16.4 -7,14.2 -21.1,23.7 -35.7,24.2 -4.1,0.1 -7.7,-0.1 -8.1,-0.4 -0.5,-0.6 2.5,-15.6 6.5,-32.4 3.8,-15.7 6.9,-36.3 7,-45.3 0,-7.2 0.3,-7.4 8.2,-3.8zM584.4,637.7c1.1,6.8 5.6,42.6 5.6,44.3 0,1.5 -1.8,1.8 -14.3,2.2 -15.9,0.6 -19,1.6 -22.9,7l-2.3,3.3 0,38.7c0,24.1 -0.4,39.1 -1,39.7 -2.1,2.1 -19.5,10.1 -28,12.8 -18.6,6.1 -33.8,8.2 -45.7,6.4 -12.8,-2 -20.3,-4.2 -32.3,-9.1 -20.5,-8.5 -45,-23.1 -66.7,-39.7 -5.5,-4.3 -12,-9.2 -14.3,-11 -5.6,-4.2 -6,-5.5 -2.3,-8.9 9.9,-9.4 21.8,-35.3 21.8,-47.6 0,-2 0.4,-5.8 0.9,-8.5 0.6,-2.6 1.5,-9.3 2.1,-14.8 1.9,-17.2 2,-17.5 4.1,-17.5 1,-0 3.3,0.8 5.1,1.8 8.7,4.8 31.7,13.4 43.1,16.1 20,4.7 27,5.5 46.2,5.4 14.4,-0.1 20.9,-0.6 32.5,-2.6 21.2,-3.7 45.6,-11.6 61,-19.8 5.4,-2.8 6.7,-2.5 7.4,1.8zM334.9,747.7c2.5,2.1 4.8,4 5.1,4.3 0.7,0.8 21.2,16.6 27.5,21.2 6.8,4.9 26.4,17.8 27.1,17.8 0.3,-0 1.8,0.8 3.2,1.9 3.3,2.2 22.2,11.9 31.3,16 8.5,3.8 19.9,7.6 30.8,10.3 11.7,2.9 37.4,3.1 50.1,0.4 10.7,-2.3 30.3,-8.7 35.3,-11.5 2.1,-1.2 4.2,-1.9 4.8,-1.6 1.5,1 1.2,39 -0.3,40.3 -1.6,1.3 -15.1,5.8 -24.3,8.2 -15.1,3.9 -20.9,4.5 -40.5,4.4 -16.3,-0 -21.1,-0.4 -29,-2.2 -8.8,-2 -23.8,-6.3 -28.5,-8.2 -1.1,-0.5 -5.7,-2.2 -10.2,-4 -29.7,-11.6 -70.8,-37.7 -107.3,-68.3 -16.6,-13.9 -27.7,-24.3 -26.8,-25.2 1.2,-1.3 9,-2.4 16.8,-2.5 7.1,-0 18.9,-1.8 25.5,-3.9 4.5,-1.4 4.4,-1.4 9.4,2.6zM243.1,755.7c1.9,1.6 9,8.3 15.9,15 28.4,27.6 65,56.3 96.5,75.8 27.2,16.9 64.4,33.1 87,38 8.8,1.9 13,2.6 23.5,4 14.3,1.8 24.2,1.9 39,-0 17.6,-2.2 26.9,-4.1 39.3,-8.1 3,-1 5.2,-1.3 5.8,-0.7 0.5,0.5 0.8,20.6 0.7,48.9l-0.3,47.9 -81.7,0.5c-80.6,0.5 -81.7,0.5 -84.5,2.6 -5.1,3.8 -6.3,7.6 -6.3,20.9 0,13.4 1.6,23.6 5,32 2.4,6 4.1,9.4 6.5,12.9 1.4,2.1 2.3,4.1 2,4.5 -0.4,0.3 -46.6,0.6 -102.8,0.6l-102.2,-0 -0.5,-47c-0.3,-32.2 -0.9,-47.8 -1.6,-49.5 -1.3,-2.8 -4.8,-6.2 -8.1,-7.9 -5.7,-2.9 -14.5,0.4 -18.2,6.9 -2.1,3.7 -2.1,4.8 -2.1,50.3l0,46.6 -3.2,0.6c-1.8,0.3 -30.1,0.4 -62.8,0.3l-59.5,-0.3 -0.3,-64c-0.2,-44 0,-66.7 0.8,-72.5 2.2,-16.5 5.6,-30.4 10,-41.5 3.9,-9.8 8.1,-18.6 12.2,-25.4 2.1,-3.4 3.8,-6.5 3.8,-6.8 0,-0.3 3.8,-5.6 8.6,-11.8 12.6,-16.7 27.4,-30.4 45,-41.8 7.4,-4.8 24.3,-13.5 30.4,-15.7 1.9,-0.6 4.4,-1.6 5.5,-2 14.4,-5.7 49.4,-12.1 82.5,-14.9 5.2,-0.5 9.8,-0.9 10.2,-1 0.3,-0 2.1,1.1 3.9,2.6zM550.5,1028.5l0,22 -53,-0c-52.8,-0 -53,-0 -59.4,-2.3 -6.9,-2.5 -14.2,-7 -17.9,-11.1 -3.2,-3.5 -8.6,-11.9 -10,-15.6 -1.4,-3.8 -3.2,-13.8 -2.5,-14.8 0.2,-0.4 32.5,-0.6 71.6,-0.5l71.2,0.3 0,22z"
   />
</vector>
```

Comment: El código va como texto!

Comment: Si pudieras dejar ver el *pathData* entero...     Respondiendo a tu pregunta... Pues si se muestra el vector en el ImageView sin problemas, entonces ignora el error

Comment: Listo, disculpen.

Comment: Pues sí que es bastante largo. Debes buscar manera de reducir el tamaño/calidad, de eso depende la longitud. En este mismo sitio web, pero en inglés hay una solución que podría servirte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51510558/simplying-vector-drawable-for-android